# Использование if/else в Python

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Только-только начал изучать Python, и застрял на операторах if/else
Написал я банальный код, спрашивающий у пользователя число, и сравнивающий его с переменной a. При попытке запустить выдаёт SyntaxError. Буду рад помощи.

```
a = 1000
b = int(input('Введите число: '))
if a == b:
  print('Вы угадали!')
  else:
    print('Вы не угадали')
```

Comment: полный текст ошибки? отступы проверь

Comment: File "main.py", line 5
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

В питоне отступы используются для того, чтоб указывать вложеность блоков кода. В частности `else` должен иметь точно такой же отступ как и `if`:

```
if a == b:
  print('Вы угадали!')
else:
  print('Вы не угадали')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё починилось!